# Kotlin reflect package and get all classes

Tags: kotlin, package, reflect

How it is possible to reflect a package and list all classes as KClass<*>?

```
fun listAllClassesInPackage(pack: String): List<KClass<*>> = ...
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val classes: List<KClass<*>> = listAllClassesInPackage("com.example")
    classes.forEach { k ->
        println(k)
    }
}
```

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520328/can-you-find-all-classes-in-a-package-using-reflection

Comment: @Tenfour04 Not really because is just for java classes. I want the class description as KClass object.

Comment: You can convert a Java Class to a KClass. `myJavaClass.kotlin`

Comment: You're right. Thx.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my solution.

```
package com.example

import org.reflections.Reflections
import org.reflections.scanners.ResourcesScanner
import org.reflections.scanners.SubTypesScanner
import org.reflections.util.ClasspathHelper
import org.reflections.util.ConfigurationBuilder
import org.reflections.util.FilterBuilder

class Test1

fun op1() = ""

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val packagePath = "com.example"
    val reflections =
        Reflections(
            ConfigurationBuilder()
                .filterInputsBy(FilterBuilder().includePackage(packagePath))
                .setUrls(ClasspathHelper.forPackage(packagePath))
                .setScanners(SubTypesScanner(false))
        )
    val typeList = reflections.getSubTypesOf(Object::class.java)
    typeList.forEach { c ->
        println(c.kotlin)
    }
}
```

Comment: I got it to work with a specific base class, but Object::class.java doesn't return anything for me

Answer (score 1):

You should check out the [kotlin reflekt plugin](https://github.com/JetBrains-Research/reflekt), though it isn't actively maintained anymore there is a working version for up to kotlin 1.7.0.

It allows you to simply call

```
Reflekt.classes().withSupertype<Any>().toSet().filter {
    it.kClass.java.package.name.startsWith("com.example")
}
```

Comment: [Link only answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259) are considered very low quality and [can get deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers), please put the important parts from the linked resource into the answer body.